# .join() TypeError, 'expected str instance' when passing in a list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the function:

```
def has_33(nums):
     newnums = "".join(nums)
     return 33 in newnums
```

When I pass in a list of integers, though, (such as [1,3,3]) I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-aa86496e9b3a> in <module>
      1 # Check
----> 2 has_33([1, 3, 3])

<ipython-input-45-3d3793a0df29> in has_33(nums)
      1 def has_33(nums):
----> 2     newnums = "".join(nums)
      3     return 33 in newnums
      4     pass

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

I want 'newnums' to become one number from all of the integers in 'nums', and then check if the integer 33 is in that new number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `newnums = "".join(map(str, nums))`

Comment: Update: I wasn't very clear on what I needed. I need to check if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join() works on strings and you are looking for a string "33", not 33 the number. Try this.

```
def has_33(nums):
     return "33" in "".join(map(str, nums))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your entire function needs only

```
return 33 in nums
```

`join` is a convenient mass concatenation for a list of strings into a single string.  It doesn't work on integers; I'm not sure what you were trying to do with that.

BTW, your `pass` statement can't be reached: it has a `return` directly in front of it.

Comment: Not the way he does it. Consider [13, 31, 10]. In his implementation, the resulting newnums would be "133110" which does contain "33" in it.

Comment: I made this change, and i'm not getting any errors. But it is returning False for what should be true. I need to check if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere.

Comment: "I want 'newnums' to become one number from all of the integers in 'nums', and then check if the integer 33 is in that new number. "

Answer (score 1):

Convert every element to a string first:

```
def has_33(nums):
    newnums = "".join([str(i) for i in nums])
    return "33" in newnums
```

Also, make sure you check for `"33"`, not `33`.

Comment: Checking for "33" instead of 33 really helped. Thanks